# Why I have no module that handle this horizontal menu in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5

I am creating this website using Joomla 2.5: http://scorejava.com/

I use a template named business_14a

I have a question for you: as you can see I have an horizzontal menu under the website logo section and a vertical main menù putted in the right side of the template

The problem is that if I go inside the administration pannel and I open my modules administration section I have only a module used for the right main menù but I have no module for the horizontal menu.

Why? How is it possibile? the horizzontal menu is not handled by a module?

This is a problem for me because I would change this horizontal menu with a drop down menu but in this case I can't put another module in its place...

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have [this](http://www.jm-experts.com/templates/business-14) template?

Have you checked the settings of the template? Some template have an own integrated menu which is used as default. As you can see in the link above you have a own position for the main menu so you can download and install other menu plugins and place them at the same position (...if you can deactivate the default one).

Have you already contacted the developer?